# Very simple step by step JBehave setup tutorial?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, bdd, jbehave

Though I have read many, but many articles on how to use JBehave, I can't get it to work. Here are the steps I went through so far:

1. Created new Java Project
2. Downloaded JBehave JAR file version 3.6.8 and added it to my build path libraries
3. Created a package called `com.wmi.tutorials.bdd.stack.specs` under the test source folder in my workspace
4. Added the JBehave JAR file to my Build path Library configuration
5. Created a JBehave story in the above-mentioned package (StackBehaviourStories.story)
6. Created a Java class in the above-mentioned package (StackBehaviourStory.java)
7. Created a Java class in the above-mentioned package (StackBehaviourSteps.java)
8. Imported the Given, Named, Then, When annotations in my Java class
9. Written two different scenarios in my JBehave story file

And still, I can't get it to work/run! =(

> **The story file:**

```
Narrative:
In order to learn to with JBehave using Eclipse
As a junior Java developer though senior in .Net and in BDD
I want to define the behaviour of a custom stack

Scenario: I push an item onto the stack
Given I have an empty stack
When  I push an item 'orange'
Then  I should count 1

Scenario: I pop from the stack
Given I have an empty stack
When  I push an item 'apple'
And   I pop the stack
Then  I should count 0
```

> **The story class**

```
package com.wmi.tutorials.bdd.stack.specs

import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStory;

public class StackBehaviourStory extends JUnitStory {
    @Override 
    public Configuration configuration() { return new MostUsefulConfiguration(); }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration()
                                      , new StackBehaviourSteps());   
    }
}
```

> **The steps class**

```
package com.wmi.tutorials.bdd.stack.specs

import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Named;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Then;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.When;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.Assert;

public class StackBehaviourSteps {
    @Given("I have an empty stack")
    public void givenIHaveAnEmptyStack() { stack = new CustomStack(); }

    @When("I push an item $item")
    public void whenIPushAnItem(@Named("item") String item) { stack.push(item); }

    @Then("I should count $expected")
    public void thenIShouldCount(@Named("expected") int expected) {
        int actual = stack.count();
        if (actual != expected) 
            throw new RuntimeException("expected:"+expected+";actual:"+actual);
    }
}
```

I'm currently using Eclipse Kepler (4.3) JEE with everything I need to use JUnit, Google App Engine, and yes, JBehave is installed correctly following the Eclipse JBehave installation tutorial.

I can't get it to work. So how can I make it work correctly using Eclipse, JBehave and JUnit?

Comment: What kind of an error are you getting?

Comment: If only I could get an error, I could know what happens! I'm simply unable to run as anything! The only available option is "Run on Server". The opened perspective is Java. Plus, the story file keeps telling me that no steps were defined for the `When`s and `Then`s, bizarrely, they are the two with parameters!... =\ I don't know where to look anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following step by step closely the [`jbehave Getting Started`](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/getting-started.html) tutorial, the **Run story** section says: *[...] the ICanToggleACell.java class will allow itself to run as a JUnit test.*

This means that the JUnit library is required in your Build path.

Using Eclipse:

1. Select your current project and right-click it, *Build path*, *Configure Build Path...*
2. Properties for *[current project]*, *Java Build Path*, *Libraries*, click *[Add Library...]*
3. Add Library, select *JUnit*, click *[Next]*
4. JUnit Library, JUnit library version, select the version you wish to use, click *[Finish]*
5. Java Build Path, click *[OK]*
6. Project Explorer, select your `ICanToggleACell.java` class, right-click it, then Run As, and click on JUnit Test

So this is the same here as for the above-example code. The `StackBehaviourStory.java` class should let itself run as a JUnit test after you add the proper library to the Java build path.

Answer (score 11):

I know I'm late to the party here but I'm posting because this is the info I wish I had a week ago as it would've saved me a lot of pain. I'm very much into the idea of BDD, but am unfortunately finding JBehave's docs to be a bit of a nightmare, especially when it comes to Maven integration. Moreover a lot of the code I found both on their website and elsewhere didn't work. Through trial and error, and lots of tutorials, I was able to piece together the following. It runs both in Maven and Eclipse, has a single binding class that maps stories to step files, and is able to find story files located in src/test/resources.

here is a working pom file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.projectvalis.st1</groupId>
  <artifactId>st1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>st1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>

        <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

       <plugin>  
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
         <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>  
         <version>${failsafe.and.surefire.version}</version>  
         <executions>  
           <execution>  
             <id>integration-test</id>  
             <goals>  
               <goal>integration-test</goal>  
               <goal>verify</goal>  
             </goals>  
           </execution>  
         </executions>  
         <configuration>  
           <includes>  
             <include>**/*Test.java</include>  
           </includes>  
         </configuration>  
       </plugin>

       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
            <executions>  
                <execution>  
                    <id>run-stories-as-embeddables</id>  
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>  
                    <configuration>  

                    <includes>  
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>  
                    </includes>  
                    <ignoreFailureInStories>false</ignoreFailureInStories>  
                    <ignoreFailureInView>false</ignoreFailureInView>  

                        <systemProperties>
                            <property>
                                <name>java.awt.headless</name>
                                <value>true</value>
                            </property>
                        </systemProperties>


                    </configuration>  
                    <goals>  
                    <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>  
                    </goals>  
            </execution>  
             </executions>
       </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>


  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

here is a sample story file

```
Narrative:
In order to work with files to compress
As a guy who wants to win a bet with cameron
I want to ensure files are ingested and processed in the manner in which the
methods in the ingest class purport to process them. 

Scenario:  Simple test to give JBehave a test drive
Given a file, a.log
When the caller loads the file as a byte array
Then the byte array that is returned contains the correct number of bytes.
```

here is a sample step file

```
package com.projectvalis.compUtils.tests.ingest;

import java.io.File;

import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Named;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Then;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.When;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.Steps;
import org.junit.Assert;

import com.projectvalis.compUtils.util.fileIO.Ingest;


    /**
     * BDD tests for the ingest class
     * @author funktapuss
     *
     */
    public class LoadByteSteps extends Steps {

        private String fNameS;
        private byte[] byteARR;

        @Given("a file, $filename")
        public void setFileName(@Named("filename") String filename) {
            File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/" + filename).getFile());
            fNameS = file.getPath();
        }

        @When("the caller loads the file as a byte array")
        public void loadFile() {
            byteARR = Ingest.loadFile(fNameS);
        }

        @Then("the byte array that is returned contains the "
                + "correct number of bytes.") 
        public void checkArrSize() {
            File file = new File(fNameS);
            Assert.assertTrue(
                    "loading error - "
                    + "the file and the resultant byte array are different sizes!", 
                    (long)byteARR.length == file.length());
        }


    }
```

and here is the generic runner

```
package com.projectvalis.compUtils.tests.runner;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.io.CodeLocations;
import org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath;
import org.jbehave.core.io.StoryFinder;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporterBuilder;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InjectableStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InstanceStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.Steps;

import com.projectvalis.compUtils.tests.ingest.LoadByteSteps;



/**
 * generic binder for all JBehave tests. Binds all the story files to the 
 * step files. works for both Eclipse and Maven command line build.  
 * @author funktapuss
 *
 */
public class JBehaveRunner_Test extends JUnitStories {

    @Override 
    public Configuration configuration() { 
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()            
                .useStoryLoader(
                        new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass().getClassLoader()))
                .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                        new StoryReporterBuilder()
                            .withDefaultFormats()
                            .withFormats(Format.HTML, Format.CONSOLE)
                            .withRelativeDirectory("jbehave-report")
                );
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        ArrayList<Steps> stepFileList = new ArrayList<Steps>();
        stepFileList.add(new LoadByteSteps());

        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), stepFileList);       
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
       return new StoryFinder().
               findPaths(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(
                       this.getClass()), 
                       Arrays.asList("**/*.story"), 
                       Arrays.asList(""));

    }

}
```

the runner lives in src/test/java/**/tests.runner.
the ingest test lives in src/test/java/**/tests.ingest.
the story files live in src/test/resources/stories.

As far as I can tell, JBehave has LOTS of options, so this certainly isn't the only way of doing things. Treat this like a template that will get you up and running quickly.

full source is on [github](https://github.com/projectvalis/java-compression-experiment).

Comment: Your contribution is welcomed. I might as well try your approach since I'm unfamiliar still with Java and its IDEs. =)

Comment: let me know how it turns out - I'm happy to help out if I can

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have extended my Steps class from Steps (from jbehave core)

Comment: It could prove interesting to show some sample code in order to illustrate your saying. =)

Answer (score 0):

i had updated the JunitStory to  JunitStories and it worked

**public class StackBehaviourStory extends JUnitStory  ---> JunitStories**