# How to run the Jbehave class through TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, jbehave

I just created feature file which is open google and enter some values in search engine and validated the search result. Also, I created a steps class file which contains given, when, and then annotations. Now, I wanna create a test runner which is used to drive the steps class file according to story file. But In my case I wanna use TestNG instead of Junit framework. I googled there are several sites were explained how to integrate the Jbehave+Junit. But So, far I didn't find any site where is the combination of Jbehave+TestNG. Since I'm trying by myself I just need some clarity on this. Can somebody give me a sample code which help me to understand better.

*Please find Sample Story:*

```
scenario: Check the google search engine
Given : Open the google home page www.google.com
When : Enter test automation in search box
Then : Proper result should be displayed in results page
```

Steps class file:

```
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Then;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.When;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class GoogleSearchEngine {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Given("Open the google home page $url")
    public static void openUrl(String url) throws Exception {
        try {

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get(url);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @When("Enter $searchKeyword in search box")
    public static void searchKeyword(String searchKeyword) throws Exception {
        try {

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gs_htif0']")).sendKeys(searchKeyword);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tsf']/center/input[1]")).click();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Then("Proper result should be displayed in results page")
    public static void result() throws Exception {
        try {

            driver.quit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Then I need to develop testrunner which used to drive the story file.

Can somebody help me to create a test runner class file using TestNG framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do something similar recently and was pleasantly surprised to discover it was NBD. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31897375/2234770) to another SO JBehave question for sample code describing how to setup JBehave. From there, simply create a testNG suite file for your JBehave tests like so:

```
<test name="all JBehave tests">

    <packages>
        <package name="com.foo.tests.jbehave.test1"/>
        <package name="com.foo.tests.jbehave.test2"/>
        <package name="com.foo.tests.jbehave.test3"/>
    </packages>

</test>
```

Remember that the JBehave's [JUnitStory](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/javadoc/core/org/jbehave/core/junit/JUnitStory.html) and [JUnitStories](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/javadoc/core/org/jbehave/core/junit/JUnitStories.html) make JBehave stuff look like JUnit stuff, so from TestNG's perspective, it's just running JUnit stuff. One thing to watch out for is integrating reporting between the two.